# Why do we put a main() function in python instead of just putting the code directly inside the "name == main" clause?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is said to be a good practice to write the following block of code in your python modules:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
  # execute only if run as a script
  main()
```

This prevents executing statements when you want to import this module into another program.

However, the curious thing over here is that **main()** function. We also need to put our code into an actual main method as follows:

```
def main()
    # All code goes here
    print("Inside main")
```

I feel that this is a roundabout way. Are there any benefits to creating a separate **main() function** and then calling it inside the **if-clause?**

**Instead what is the harm in writing the code directly inside the if-clause?**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # All code goes here
    print("Inside main")
```

Comment: You can import and test or reuse main elsewhere, you can't do that with inline code.

Comment: @Barmar - The question has nothing to do with the if statement, its about whether its contents need to be encapsulated.

Comment: @Sayse Understanding why we use the if statement in general should explain why the contents need to be encapsulated.

Comment: Reopened the question as it was not a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163

Comment: @tripleee would you mind reopening this question ? It is **NOT** asking what the `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard is doing, it's asking "why put the main code in a main function".

Comment: The two questions are closely related and the duplicate covers both quite well IMHO. If you disagree, I'd think posting a new answer to the duplicate would be more appropriate.

Comment: @tripleee I totally disagree indeed. The OP clearly states he knows what the guard is doing and why we're using it - "This prevents executing statements when you want to import this module into another program." -, what he asks is why putting the main code in a function instead of having it directly under the guard. I definitly don't see how this is a dup.

Comment: @tripleee "If you disagree, I'd think posting a new answer to the duplicate would be more appropriate" => certainly not, because those are totally unrelated questions - cf jonrsharpe ans Sayse comments too - _they_ did read and get the question instead of stopping at the mention of the "main" guard and concluding the question was about the use of the guard.

Comment: Fine; let's hope these comments also prompt visitors to review the answers there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However, the curious thing over here is that main() function. We also need to put our code into an actual main method as follows:

Well, you dont **need** to do so. Actually if all you want is a plain script (something that's not going to be used as a module), you don't even "need" any function at all, you could as well put all your code directly at the top-level. BUT this will not make for clean, maintainable, testable code.

> I feel that this is a roundabout way. Are there any benefits to creating a separate main() function and then calling it inside the if-clause

Quite simply the same benefits as you get from using functions (and modules and classes) to organize your code: clean, readable, testable, maintainable code. Just ask yourself how you are going to test your main function if you don't have a main function ?

Comment: I don't feel that this answers the question. This answers essentially states that we're adding a main() function because we're just putting everything into functions. However, if we have the code under the if-clause. Also, what if all that main() code goes inside the if-clause? That's still organized IMHO because if you look at the script you will look directly at the if-clause and know that that is what will get run.

Comment: Well, you ask mainly two things: 1/ why we "need" to put the main code into a function, and 2/ what are the benefits. The answers are 1/ you actually don't "need" to do so, and 2/ the main benefit is that you can call this "main" code as function, which allow you to a/ unittest your main function (how do you unittest this code else ?) and b/ possibly call this main function (from another module / script / whatever) too. And this answers the "what are the harms of not doing so": you cannot unit test this part of the code nor call this code from another module.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get time to read your comments for 4 hours, until now. I read your comments and they answer my question just fine. Thanks a lot for replying! :)

Comment: I just went through the comments thread on the question. Thanks for reopening my question and insisting that it's different than the other one. I really appreciate your help!